# Jquery Append new row to the html table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using jQuery to append rows dynamically in html table everything is working like a charm but when I try to add new row it will losses the value of inputs in the table I don't understand why?
Please help me in this

While I add the first Row:

[image]

And after clicking Add New Row again it will loss the input value of previous row:

[image]

This is my Code to append Rows in jquery:

```
$("#btnAddNewRow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ScheduleId = <%= ScheduleID%>;
    var tblWeeklyHtml = $('#tblweeklyData > tbody');
    alert(tblWeeklyHtml.clone().html());
    var s = tblWeeklyHtml.html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/hris2/manager/schedule/schedule.aspx/updateweeklyTableTitle",
        data: '{Schedule_Id: ' + ScheduleId + ', WrId: "-1", Title: "" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            var NewWrID;
            var Day1 = new Date($('#txtDate0').html());
            var Day2 = new Date($('#txtDate1').html());
            var Day3 = new Date($('#txtDate2').html());
            var Day4 = new Date($('#txtDate3').html());
            var Day5 = new Date($('#txtDate4').html());
            var Day6 = new Date($('#txtDate5').html());
            var Day7 = new Date($('#txtDate6').html());

            var Month1 = Day1.getMonth() + 1;
            var Month2 = Day2.getMonth() + 1;
            var Month3 = Day3.getMonth() + 1;
            var Month4 = Day4.getMonth() + 1;
            var Month5 = Day5.getMonth() + 1;
            var Month6 = Day6.getMonth() + 1;
            var Month7 = Day7.getMonth() + 1;

            NewWrID = response.d;
            s += '<tr class="off">';
            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableTitle(this.value,' + ScheduleId + ',this.id);" class="weeklyTable" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day1.getDate() + ',' + Month1 + ',' + Day1.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable"  style="width: 60px;" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day2.getDate() + ',' + Month2 + ',' + Day2.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable" style="width: 60px;" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day3.getDate() + ',' + Month3 + ',' + Day3.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable" style="width: 60px;" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day4.getDate() + ',' + Month4 + ',' + Day4.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable" style="width: 60px;" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day5.getDate() + ',' + Month5 + ',' + Day5.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable" style="width: 60px;" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day6.getDate() + ',' + Month6 + ',' + Day6.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable" style="width: 60px;" /></td>';

            s += '<td class="gridCellEmpData">';
            s += '<input type="text" id=' + NewWrID + ' onchange="updateweeklyTableData(-1,this.id,' + Day7.getDate() + ',' + Month7 + ',' + Day7.getFullYear() + ',this.value);" class="weeklyTable" style="width: 60px;" /></td>';
            s += '</tr">';
            tblWeeklyHtml.html(s);
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Because you're replacing tblWeeklyHtml's html with s everytime you do your ajax call. You should be appending s to the body of the table.

Comment: No i just assign the previous html to s and then append further tr's with s+="<tr></tr>"

Comment: There is no reason to replace the existing Html by setting s = to it, just append the new row to the table body.

Comment: Hey it is retainning the first input values but now it is appending two rows instead of 1 and when i click again it adds four rows instead of 1

Comment: You probably aren't clearing the value in s before doing the row creation.

Comment: How to clear then?

Comment: Can you post your modified code?

Comment: tblWeeklyHtml.append(s); just add this in the above code instead of tblWeeklyHtml.html(s);

and this is how i and getting the html of table 
 var tblWeeklyHtml=$('#tblweeklyData > tbody');
 var s = tblWeeklyHtml..html();

Comment: Since you are appending to the table body, there is no reason to set s = tblWeeklyHtml.html(), replace that line with var s = "";

Comment: It worked thankyou :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer below, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append to the body of your table, not replace the body with s, so change from:

```
 tblWeeklyHtml.html(s);
```

To:

```
 $(tblWeeklyHtml).append(s);
```

Also, since you are appending to the table body, it is not necessary to get the html of the table body inside s, so initialize it to empty string.